# php add http links to variable

Tags: php, mysql, http, variables

I'm new to PHP and programming in general so go easy with me!

I have a (drupal) mysql database and I want to select all url links from a data field and put them in a variable. There could be one link or many.

So this is what's in the database:

```
<ul>
<li><a href"link1.php">link1</a></li>
<li><a href"link2.php">link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need this in a variable. The variable will then be submitted via a hidden form field to an ASP page to display the data.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php

global $base_url;

$iconPath = $base_url . "/sites/default/files/icons/";

if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2) ) {
$nodenew = node_load(arg(1));

//print node_load(arg(1));// returns a blank
}

$relatedPages2 = $nodenew->field_related_pages[0]['value'];

$pagesArray=explode('<a href="',$relatedPages2);
$howmanyItemsOnArray = count($pagesArray);
$start = 0;
$end = $howmanyItemsOnArray;
$split = 2;

$str = '';
$str.= "<ul>";

for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
$str.= "<li><a href=\"".$pagesArray[$i]."\">".$clearPagesArray[$i]."</a></li>";
if(($i) % ($split) == $split-1){
}
}

$str.="</ul>";

//print($str);
//print relatedPages2;

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is defined your `arg()` function? What is it?

Comment: If I'm being honest I haven't been able to identify the arg() as it's possibly in Drupal core. The code snippet above was in a Drupal block and I've added to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi replace the line like this,

```
$str = "<ul>";   
for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $str.= "<li><a href='".$pagesArray[$i]."'>".$clearPagesArray[$i]."</a></li>";
}

$str.="</ul>";
```

Hope this will work